# Allow id attributes with simple_format helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, html-helper

As a proof of concept here's some console output first:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :010 > x = "<span id='c_3'>s</span>"
 => "<span id='c_3'>s</span>" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :011 > helper.simple_format(x)
 => "<p><span>s</span></p>"
```

The reason for this is that the Rails helper method `simple_format` call the `sanitize` method at the very end of it's execution and that method strips out attributes.

I know that `sanitize` will allow you to specify attributes that should not be stripped.  My question is:  Is it possible to somehow pass the "white listed" attribute (id in this case) THROUGH simple_format ?

thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a white-list, but you can disable sanitization completely by doing

```
simple_format(x, :sanitize => false)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format

Comment: AH! I see now.  Looking in the source i see this line `  text = sanitize(text) unless options[:sanitize] == false` which totally clicks.  Thanks a lot @Dogbert !

Comment: Actually, to disable sanitization, you need to use the _third_ argument, not the second, which is "html options", another hash.  So the correct form would be <pre><code>simple_format(x, {}, :sanitize => false)</code></pre>

Answer (score 5):

```
simple_format(x,{}, :sanitize => false)
```